# How to use android-async-http library

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am trying to use the android-async-http library for asynchronous file upload to the server. The callback is inside a method I call upload. However, I get an error when trying to call the method from an AsyncTask class. Can anybody spot where a getting the error?
Here is my upload method:

```
public void upload(String title, String genre, String description, String songuri, int accountId) {

    File song = new File(songuri);

    try {
        String url = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.audio_upload_url))
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("title", title)
                .appendQueryParameter("tags", genre)
                .appendQueryParameter("description", description)
                .appendQueryParameter("accountId", String.valueOf(accountId))
                .build().toString();

        AsyncHttpResponseHandler httpResponseHandler = createHTTPResponseHandler();

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        // this path could be retrieved from library or camera
        //String imageFilePath = "/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG.jpg";
        //params.put("data", new File(imageFilePath));

        params.put("song", song);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(url, params, httpResponseHandler);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And here is how I initialize the AsyncHttpResponseHandler class.

```
 public AsyncHttpResponseHandler createHTTPResponseHandler() {
    AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler = new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(int position, int length) {
            super.onProgress(position, length);

            // progressBar.setProgress(position);
            //progressBar.setMax(length);
}


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

        }

    };

    return handler;
}
```

And in my AsyncTask class, this is how I am calling the upload method.

```
@Override
    protected UploadFragment doInBackground(UploadFragment... params) {
        String title = titleEt.getText().toString();
        String description = descriptionEt.getText().toString();

        int user_id;
        userdetails = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
        User user = userdetails.get(0);
        user_id = user.getUserid();

        upload(title, "genre", description, songPath, user_id);
        return null;
    }
```

I get the error in the last line of onPreExecute method of the AsyncTask class because of leaked Window, which implies that I am getting an error when executing doInBackground() method.

Comment: library already performing async task, no need to create yours

Answer (score 0):

Use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library for Network Communication referred by google . In android-async-http-library we can't cancel particular request but it possible with volley.